# PyQt5: How to display web image with text together in QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, web-crawler

I made a news crawler that crawls news' title and contents with 'requests' lib.
All the crawled data are displayed in QTextBrowser so that I can copy and paste to somewhere.

The problem is I have no idea on bringing images from the news content so that I can copy images with text together.

If QTextBrowser cannot do such thing, what would be a best solution to get all data from the news? To make me easier to copy and paste?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: By default Qt doesn't access network resources. You could interface QTextBrowser (or better, its document) with QNetworkAccessManager. Remember that the Qt rich text engine only supports a limited subset of HTML, alternatively consider the QtWebEngine module (which is obviously much more memory intensive).